# Two separate disks, no grub displayed but boots straight to Windows

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub, uefi

I have a laptop that contains two SSD disks. Legacy mode is completely disabled in BIOS, so I'm most likely using UEFI only.

The bigger disk was used to install a fresh copy of Windows. I then used Rufus to transfer Debian to my USB stick and was able to install Debian in UEFI mode.

When I reboot, I do not get grub, but it boots straight to Windows. If I press the F2 hotkey and then select to boot Debian - then grub magically appears. I can then select to boot to Windows or Debian.

I have already disabled fastboot and the command `bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` is not helping me out at all.

How can I fix grub so that it's going to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with GRUB but with UEFI. UEFI is likely defaulting to Windows Boot Manager. You can change the default boot in UEFI settings.